# Mouse Event handling

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I have a WPF window .I want when my mouse cursor is outside the Control area of window and I am clicking on it I want my window to disappear is there any mechanism of achieving it thorough WPF??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Mouse.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.capture.aspx) method. This lets you get mouse events even if the mouse is outside your control.

Be sure to release the mouse once you're done though calling Capture with null.

> To release mouse capture, call Capture passing null as the element to capture.

In the constructor place this:

```
public MyControl()
{
    //Other stuff like initialize component
    Mouse.Capture(this);
    MouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
}
```

Then implement that method:

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.IsMouseOver)
    {
        Close(); //your closing implementation here
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am new to wpf can you please elaborte ??Msdn clarifications are not enough for me in Capture mouse

Comment: Here you go.. hope that clarifies things :)

Comment: Hi Arcturus,I think I was not clear with my probelm statement My Wpfcontrol is a Window and outside of my Window/Client area is desktop context.I tried putting the code snippet you had shared but while I am clicking mouse outside on client area/wpf window context I cannot see any call coming to OnMouseLeftButtonDown method

Comment: Hi.. If you want to receive events outside your window, you might want to look at Windows Hooks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx . This is a lot complexer btw ;)